# Live.js Not Updating

Tags: refresh

I have a pos system that can write a order to a .txt file everytime something is changed (added or removed) in the order. I am trying to get a drive thru customer order display screen solution. I got everything working through using wamp webserver and displaying the content as html and having live.js refresh the chrome browser whenever there is an order update, however I am having issues when there isnt a refresh for over 5 minuets, it takes live.js 30-50 seconds to detect that the .txt file has changed and actually refresh the page. I need a solution that will always work instantly which live.js does fine until the computer idles for over 3-7 minuets.

Anyone experienced with live.js or have another solution that you think would perform better?

I can post the live.js code here if you guys want but its just the default code from live.js

Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

just add to the head

```
meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1"
```

Will refresh the page every 1 second.

Comment: This is not the same thing as live.js at all.